# Substring on an html tag containing quotes

Tags: c#, string, parsing, substring

How can I properly use substring, at least, make it work ?

I want to find the position of this substring `'#fff'\">` in the stringString `this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'\">Choose a translation mode,`

I'm doing this :

```
string substrToSearch = "'#fff'\\\">";
int substrPosition = stringString.IndexOf(substrToSearch);
```

Unfortunately, substrPosition = -1, and it is not working.
May someone help me ?

EDIT SOLVED :

I don't realy understand why I can't do this `string quote = " " ";` but I can do this `quote = " \" "` ,in fact I know that I can but.. here, the "\" is used as an escaping character, so why in the substring that I'm searching it is not interpreted as an escape character but as simple text ?

To me , `string substrToSearch = "'#fff'\">";`, substrToSearch is '#fff'"> as `\"` = `"`.

To be simple, why `\"` is not interpreted as an escape character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
string substrToSearch = "'#fff'\">";
```

the stringString is not ecapsed when you access it

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void StringIndex
    {
        var stringString = "this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'\">Choose a translation mode,:";
        var substrToSearch = "'#fff'\">";
        var substrPosition = stringString.IndexOf(substrToSearch);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you even if I still don't understand.. Try to understand my editing on my question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your added question is fundamental to the concept of string escaping. The syntax `string quote = " " ";` is problematic because a compiler would think that the string ended with the second quote and not the third one.  String escaping allows representing an **actual quotation mark** with `\"`, so the **actual value** of `" \" "` is `"`, not `\"`.